# how to test a particular method using python

Tags: python, testing, plone

I want to write a test for a login page. The method is check_input and the code looks like below

```
def check_input(self):
    form = self.request.form
    username = form.get('name',"")
    password = form.get('password',"")
    session = getSession()
    error = ''
    print session
    if (username == '' and password == ''):
        error = "error: you must enter both username and password"          
    if (username!='') and(password == ''):
        error = "you must enter password"


    if (username and password) not in ['', None]:
        result = session.execute("select UserName,Password from membership where UserName='%s' && Password='%s' "%(username,password))
        if result:
            records = result.fetchall()
            if not records:
                error = 'username and password do not match'



    if not error:
        return self.template_success(name=username)
    else:
        return self.template(error = error)
```

What I want to test is whether the enter both username and password or not and also i want to check whether he/she gives password or not. I want to check whether this method properly or not. Tell me the necessary things which i want to do the test in terminal.

Comment: Have you tried using something like doctests or the unittest framework?

Comment: looks like you are using a framework to write a web application.  Perhaps the framework has test facilities?  Unless you tell us what framework you are using we are unable to help

Comment: we are using plone framework

Comment: Why are you writing a login page? Plone already has a full authentication system. Use the login page it comes with. (Also note that Plone is not a framework, it's a content management system. If you treat it as a web framework you will be very unhappy very fast).

Comment: we created a small website in plone . In that website we have a login menu . For that we write a test code . Our login code looks like the above . for that we write a test code like this

Comment: @user2277525: OK. You would probably be much happier if you used the functionality that is built in-in Plone instead. The membership database, where does that come from? Is that used outside Plone?

Comment: we used mysql database . and then we have a membership table. Those username and password comes from the membership table..

Comment: Let's discuss this in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28165/room-for-regebro-and-user2277525

Comment: yes already created the membership table...

Comment: OK, it seems like you can't chat, but discussing this in this form is pointless, so I have to give up here. However, you are trying to use Plone to do a bad implementation of functionality that is already included in Plone. I recommend you to not do that. Delete the login form, delete the Membership table, you don't need them. Plone already includes all that.

Comment: we created a small website named as optiluxparadise . For that we created login menu . that login menu is not for default as u told...

Comment: Plone *does* have user management and logins built in. This is a fact. You should use them instead of implementing your own. Fact. Accept it or not, this is what you should do.

Comment: plone as default login page i know that..

Comment: plone as default login page i know that..but what i did i just created one site named s optilux cinemas.. in that site i created one menu "Login" for my optilux site(not default site login).. so now what i need is to write test code for my own loginpage code which i posted before.. so pls tell me how to test  the code in teminal itself

Comment: plone as default login page i know that..but what i did i just created one site named s optilux cinemas.. in that site i created one menu "Login" for my optilux site(not default site login).. so now what i need is to write test code for my own loginpage code which i posted before.. so pls tell me how to test the code in teminal itself

Comment: You should use default functionality, and there is not much use in writing your own login page either. If you want the design/text to be different, you can override it, or you can write a new page, but using the same (or very similar) form. Since you are new to Plone, I **strongly** urge yo to simply use the standard login page. Plone is *not* easy, and it is *not* a webframework.

Comment: do u have skype id...if so  we will chat from skype...

Comment: please help us we have so many doubts...

Comment: @user2277525: I am helping you. You need to listen to the advice. Is there something unclear about it?

Answer (score 1):

You are in luck, as Plone does have a testing framework that you should use.

https://ploneapptesting.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @user2277525: First of all, don't wrote your own login system. Second of all, the link above tells you how to do testing in Plone.